# GTM event only triggered when certain element inside target is clicked

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

With GTM, I am tracking the clicks on all cards containing a certain id (`go-to-store-card`)

a card looks like this:

```
<a id="go-to-store-card-vuori" href="https://vuoriclothing.com/" target="_blank">{children}</a>
```

But the event is only triggered when the user clicks a certain element nested inside those cards.

```
<span>Go to store</span>
```

Nothing is tracked when clicking anywhere else on the cards. Any idea why?

[GTM config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDMw1.png)

[Tracked event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcdWi.png)

I am wondering if there is some kind of confusion with the text being "go to store" on the span

Comment: Have you tried using the `click element` rather than `click id` trigger condition?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot

GTM listen 2 click events

1. gtm.click and this detect the click from the span.(And you set the trigger use this type)
2. gtm.linkClick. This detect the `<a>` element you are trying to target.

---

So the solution here is change your trigger type from All Elements to Just Links

@A_Patterson mentioned a better way to capture

Here is the html you have

```
<a id="go-to-store-card-vuori" href="https://vuoriclothing.com/" target="_blank">
  {children.. <span></span>}
</a>
```

Sometimes GTM will capture the click event from the {child}

There are 2 ways to setup the trigger.

1. First is use `Just Link` and target the element id. Because `Just Link` will only focus on the  element
2. Second is use `All Elements` and use css selector to capture:
   `a#go-to-store-card-vuori, a#go-to-store-card-vuori *`

This will trigger when user click the  element or anything inside the

[image]